# How to output a formatted string from a JSON model class

Tags: c#, json, reflection, system.text.json

I want something like the following:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      var myArgs = new ArgClass();
        
      // myArgs is populated via System.Text.Json deserialization
        
      Console.WriteLine(myArgs.ToArguments());
   }
}

public interface IArguments {}

public class ArgClass : IArguments
{
   [JsonPropertyName("propertyA")]
   public string PropA {get; set;}
    
   [JsonPropertyName("propertyA")]
   public int PropB {get; set;}
}

public static class IArgumentsExt
{
   public static string ToArguments(this IArguments ArgObj)
   {
      var argString = new StringBuilder();

      //Code to build argument string

      return argString.ToString();
    } 
}
```

So that the `Console.Writeline()` would output the following string:

> -argument propertyA="some text" -argument propertyB=123

I feel like this is something that has to be done with reflection, but I know nothing about reflection. I have tried really hard to avoid situations that require it because everything I read (or watch) says it's slow.

The reason I want to do it like this is that the JSON string that I am deserializing has more properties that I am interested in at to moment, but I might want to use more of them in the future; like if I add more features to my app later. As it stands I can add `PropC` to `ArgClass` to pick up another JSON property. In which case I would want the new output of `ToArguments()` to be:

> -argument propertyA="text a" -argument propertyB=123 -argument propertyC="text c"

without having to modify `ToArguments()`.

Or maybe make another class:

```cs
public class OtherArgClass : IArguments
{
   [JsonPropertyName("propertyD")]
   public string PropD {get; set;}
    
   [JsonPropertyName("propertyE")]
   public int PropE {get; set;}
}
```

and have an output of `myOtherArgs.ToArguments()`:

> -argument propertyD="some other text" -argument propertyE=45.678

again, without modifying `ToArguments()`.

I am using .Net 7 Preview and System.Text.Json (not Newtonsoft/Json.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **System.Reflection** is needed to achieve your required value.

1. Get the properties of the instance which applies the `JsonPropertyName` attribute.
2. Iterate the properties.

   2.1. Get the property name from the `JsonPropertyName` attribute.

   2.2. Get the property value and serialize.

   2.3. Add both values into `StringBuilder`.

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

public static class IArgumentsExt
{
   public static string ToArguments(this IArguments ArgObj)
   {
      var argString = new StringBuilder();
       
       PropertyInfo[] props = ArgObj.GetType().GetProperties()
           .Where(x => x.CustomAttributes.Any(y => y.AttributeType.Name == nameof(JsonPropertyNameAttribute)))
           .ToArray();

       foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
       {       
           string propertyName = ((JsonPropertyNameAttribute)prop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonPropertyNameAttribute))).Name;

           // Or
           // string propertyName = prop.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyNameAttribute>().Name;

           string propertyValue = JsonSerializer.Serialize(prop.GetValue(ArgObj));
           argString.Append($"-argument {propertyName}={propertyValue} ");
       }

      return argString.ToString()
          .Trim();
    } 
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nH6kLM)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Change```string propertyName = prop.Name;``` to ```string propertyName = prop.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyNameAttribute>().Name;``` and this will be the exact answer I was looking for. This Got me most of the way and IntelliSense helped me get the rest.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, and sorry didn't read the output carefully.  While I think that would recommend to query those properties which apply the `JsonPropertyName` attribute. You may refer to the updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: why use ```GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonPropertyNameAttribute))``` instead of ```GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyNameAttribute>()?```

Comment: Both have the same outcome. That statement I use for demonstration purposes.